# find photos shot by a certain type of camera via terminal

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, find, camera, photo

I have a huge collections of photos shot with different cameras on my computer. Now, I would like to find all photos which has been shot with a certain camera via the terminal.

I think it should be possible to find them according to their exif data!?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at exiftool. Something like

```
sudo apt-get install exiftool
cd FOLDERWITHYOURCOLLECTION
exiftool -a -r -Model -Directory -Filename -T * |grep YOURMODELHERE > list
```

You will get a file `list` with content like:

```
CanoScan 5600F  1992/07/05      1992_0705_120100.jpg
CanoScan 5600F  1992/07/05      1992_0705_120400.jpg
```

With the model first, then the folder, then the file name.